# Simplifying expressions that include symbolic variables

Tags: matlab

I am trying to automatically simplify my MATLAB output, but so far I have only been able to achieve it manually.

After my code executes I'm presented with the following data:

```
((yf^2*((138454006717812460917559315575*a^2)/20282409603651670423947251286016 + 20)^2 - 20*yf^2*((19169511976216058056763775016476506759529226598462437580625*a^4)/6582018229284824168619876730229402019930943462534319453394436096 - (39872549173714278543306705994157*a^2)/40564819207303340847894502572032 + 25))^(1/2) - (- (138454006717812460917559315575*a^2)/20282409603651670423947251286016 - 20)*yf)/(10*yf^2)
```

where 'yf' and 'a' are symbolic variables. However, during a portion of the code, these variables are assigned specific values. Accordingly, if I copy that data above and put it back into MATLAB it then aknowledges that 'yf' and 'a' have specific values and provides me the following:

```
41734615734664636717495154985753713986168093218527630622251194499100^(1/2)/6788754250849186019091129738088810 + 1362181378384807202322670643292642/678875425084918601909112973808881
```

Which is much better, because the variables are gone. However it is still a very large piece of data to look at, and if I repeat the process of putting this answer back into MATLAB then it finally spits out the answer of 2.9581.

How can I make this process automatic, so that when I execute my code I am straight away presented with 2.9581?

Comment: It's a little hard to answer without knowing why or in what format you are getting the above output. If the above are returned as strings, you would be able to make use of the `eval` command [more here](http://au.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/eval.html).

Comment: Hi @KhalidAbdulla, the output is returned as numerical data with symbolic variables, I am not working with strings. Thanks

Comment: Hi @Matt, ah symbolic expressions... I should've read the question more carefully. It turns out `eval` works for these as well, so I'll post as answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option would be to use `eval`. This can be done in one line with just your expression as the argument passed in.

In example below `eval` used before `yf` `a` assigned returns the same expression. But after they're assigned gives a numeric answer:

```
syms yf a
expression = ((yf^2*((138454006717812460917559315575*a^2)/20282409603651670423947251286016 + 20)^2 - 20*yf^2*((19169511976216058056763775016476506759529226598462437580625*a^4)/6582018229284824168619876730229402019930943462534319453394436096 - (39872549173714278543306705994157*a^2)/40564819207303340847894502572032 + 25))^(1/2) - (- (138454006717812460917559315575*a^2)/20282409603651670423947251286016 - 20)*yf)/(10*yf^2);
eval(expression)
yf = 1.0;
a = 2.0;
eval(expression)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can substitue subexpressions using `subs` and convert the resulting expression without variables to a numeric value using `double`:

```
s= ((yf^2*... % Your symbolic expression here
s= subs(s,yf,100) % Replace yf with value, for example, 100
s= subs(s,a,101) % Replace a with value, for example, 101
v= double(s) % Convert the symbolic expression to a numeric value
```

Comment: Or with just one explicit call to `subs`: `s = subs(s,{yf,a},{100,101})`.